# C++ Forward Declaration (Pointer) - Access member

Tags: c++, class, pointers, member, forward-declaration

I'm working with OpenGL and DirectX, and I've started developing the basics for the object-oriented game classes. The structure of the current classes is as follows:

Object
---|---Actor
---------|---Pawn
---------|---Controller

So I have the `Pawn` and `Controller` class that inherit `Actor` which inherits `Object`.

The problem is that I need to have a reference of `Controller` in the pawn class and an instance of `Pawn` in the controller class.
Because of this I forward-declared `Pawn` and `Controller` in `Actor.h`:

```
// Actor.h

// (...) Actor Declaration (...)

class Pawn;
class Controller;
```

And then in `Pawn.h`:

```
// Pawn.h

class Pawn : public Actor
{
private:
    Controller* controller;
public:
    void DoSomethingWithController(void);
}
```

This is all good, no errors and all. The problem is when I want to access the members in that class:

```
void Pawn::DoSomethingWithController(void)
{
    // this->controller-> can't access members like this (members not found)
}
```

So, what should I do to be able to have a pointer of Controller in Pawn and a pointer to a Pawn in my Controller keeping them in different files (.h and .cpp) and at the same time being able to access it's members?

Thank you for your time. :D

[if more information is required I'll provide it]

Comment: Just `#include "Controler.h"` in Pawn.cpp.

Comment: That's not a problem. Pawn.cpp is not included by Pawn.h. I hope.

Comment: I see what you mean, how didn't I remember I can include .h files in .cpp *extreme face palm*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forward declaration says to compiler that given type will be provided further. Compiler doesn't have a clue about fields or members of that type. Therefore you need to include corresponding .h file in your .cpp file (the place you access the members of "controller" class).